# BeautifulSoup with Python, extracting child node content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract all comments within a trip advisor page for a small analytic project, I was able to successfully scrape the comments in the previous year, however I am facing difficulty as I think tripadvisor has updated their html-code.

Here is the link that I am trying to crawl.
https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Attraction_Review-g294265-d4457226-Reviews-Jem-Singapore.html

And here are my codes which I have used but unsuccessfully obtained the data.

```
            source = driver.page_source
            data = bs(source, 'html.parser')
            body = data.find('body')           
            #script = body.find_all("div",class_="bPhtn")        #IRsGHoPm 
            script = body.find_all("div",class_="eeqnt")         #I have trouble directing the right element to scrape the relevant html scripting. 
                                                                 #I understand that i need to get this class with the section-nth-child[7] but i am unsure how to do it
            
            if logging: print(f"line {inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).lineno}:", "beginScrape():", "Get all data in comment...")
            for i in script:
                data = i.find('span')
                currData = data.get_text()
                tempData.append(currData)
```

Ps. any help to obtain the right script would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Apparently this set of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the page source you will see there are bunch of `div` tags with class name of `WlYyy diXIH dDKKM` (whatever that means) which hold span tag that holds comments in turn. Grabbing all those tags will give you all comments in a single page. In order to get every comment about the product you need to loop through every comments page which can be done as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}

comment_page = 0
number_of_comments = 82
comments = []
while True:
    url = f'https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Attraction_Review-g294265-d4457226-Reviews-or{comment_page}-Jem-Singapore.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'lxml')

    raw_comments = soup.find_all('div', class_='WlYyy diXIH dDKKM')
    comments += [each.span.text for each in raw_comments if each.span]
    
    # break once grabbing every comment
    if comment_page > number_of_comments:
        break
    
    comment_page += 10
```

`comments` list would look like:

```
Good place to walk around, filled with a lot of different food stores, as there are three shopping malls back to back. Tho because of covid restrictions may not be as pleasant as the non-covid periods.

This place has a rather large variety of both raw and cooked japanese food. The promotion with uob can be attractive, this month it is a 1-1 promotion of lobster salad roll. Some months are salmon sashimi

Jem has all the upper middle brands you'd want - like uniqlo, kinokuniya. It even has a Don Don donki now! Super convenient walkway to the mrt, and next to other malls. 

this mall is easy ot reach, located near Jurong East station with NW line adn EW line that can reach Changi airport. Air condition mall with huge range of food in there. Huge supermarket and lots of shop

A nice mall with a good variety of standard and upmarket storesI specially like the Seiko Store. Wonderful.2 thumbs up.Cheers.

...
```